# Counting duration values

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, comparative-review, lodash.js

I have a `durations` as such:

```
[{'duration': 3600}, {'duration': 3600}]
```

And I want the output to be `{3600: 2}`, where 2 is the number of occurrences of 3600.

My first attempt is use a loop, as such:

```
    var count = {};
    for (var d of durations) {
        var length = d.duration;
        if (length in count) {
            count[length] += 1;
        }
        else {
            count[length] = 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(count);
```

The second attempt uses [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) in lodash:

```
    function foo(result, value) {
        var length = value.duration;

        if (length in result) {
            result[length] += 1;
        }
        else {
            result[length] = 1;
        }

        return result;
    }
    var reduced = _.reduce(durations, foo, {});
    console.log(reduced);
```

As can be seen, this second attempt is still as verbose as before.

Is there a way to write the iteratee function `foo` more conform to functional programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First point

Don't add quotes around property names when defining JS objects.

```
[{'duration': 3600}, {'duration': 3600}]

// should be

[{duration: 3600}, {duration: 3600}]
```

### You state

> *"And I want the output to be {3600: 2}, where 2 is the number of occurrences of 3600."*

Which is not that clear. Going by your code I assume you want  `[{duration: 60}, {duration: 60}, , {duration: 10}]` converted to  `{60:2, 10:1}`

I will also assume that all array items contain an object with the property named `duration`

Using these assumptions for the rest of the answer.

### Rewrite

Taking your first snippet and turning it into a function.

- You don't need the `if (length in count) {`, you can just use `if (count[d.duration]) {`
- The object `count` and `d` should be constants as you don't change them.
- Using a t[ernary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) you can reduce the 6 lines of the if else to one line.

Code

```
function countDurations(durations) {
    const counts = {};
    for (const {duration: len} of durations) {
        counts[len] = counts[len] ? counts[len] + 1 : 1;
    }
    return counts;
}
```

Or a little less verbose as a arrow function

```
const countDur = dur => dur.reduce((c, {duration: l}) => (c[l] = c[l]? c[l] + 1: 1, c), {});
```

or

```
const countDurs = durs => 
    durs.reduce((counts, {duration: len}) => 
        (counts[len] = counts[len] ? counts[len] + 1 : 1, counts)
    , {}
);
```

### Rewrite 2

The second snippet is algorithmicly the same, just uses a different iteration method.

- JavaScript has [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) so you don't need to use a external library.
- Separating the iterator inner block into a function `count`

Code

```
const count= (cnt, {duration: len}) => (cnt[len] = cnt[len] ? cnt[len] + 1 : 1, cnt);
const countDurations = durations => durations.reduce(count, {});
```

Or encapsulating the `count` function via closure

```
const countDurations = (()=> {
    const count = (cnt, {duration: len}) => (cnt[len] = cnt[len] ? cnt[len] + 1 : 1, cnt);
    return durations => durations.reduce(count, {});
})();
```

### Functional?

> *"Is there a way to write the iterate function foo more conform to functional programming?"*

JavaScript is not designed to be a functional language (it is impossible to create pure functions) so  It is best to use functional as a guide rather than a must.

### Almost pure

The second rewrite is more along the functional approach, but functional purist would complain that the reducer function has side effects by modifying the counter. You can create a copy of the counts each call as follows..

```
const counter = (c, {duration: len}) => (c = {...c}, (c[len] = c[len] ? c[len] + 1 : 1), c);
const countDurations = durations => durations.reduce(counter, {});
```

However this add significant memory and processing overhead with zero benefit (apart from a functional pat on the back).

### Note

- This answer uses [destructuring property name alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) so check for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear what you mean by "functional".

The use of `reduce` is nifty, and correctly done, but it seem like [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) programming. The realization that a lot of loop-like actions can be represented in terms of `reduce` (fold, aggregate, etc) is *important* to functional programing, but it should no more be your first choice than a while-loop.

The fact that it's verbose isn't necessarily a problem. It *suggests* that you might be failing at a general goal:

> Write what you mean.

One of the things that makes functional programming good is that it helps us do that.
Javascript has limited tools for directly declaring lists. What you *mean* to do is declare a Dictionary from the Set of `duration` values to the Count of the source array Filtered by the respective duration. Or even better you could use a grouping function.

You could bring in a library for the task, which may be a good idea, or you could compromise a little.

```
function getCounts(items, key){
  let c = {};
  for(let item of items){
    c[key(item)] = items.filter(function(i){
        return key(i) === key(item);
      }).length;
  }
  return c;
};
counts = getCounts(durations, function(i){ return i['duration']; })'
```

You'll notice that that's quite inefficient. We could make it less wasteful, but it'd be less terse.

Comment: The introduction of your answer is good, but the code is not since its complexity is \$\mathcal O(n^2)\$.

Comment: Yeah, don't actually use that code.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the verboseness of the code, you should extract the main idea of that code into a function:

```
function histogram(data, key) {
    const count = {};
    for (let item of data) {
        const value = data[key];
        count[value] = (count[value] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

That way you can write your code as:

```
console.log(histogram(durations, 'duration'));
```

I first tried a simple `count[value]++`, but that didn't work since `undefined + 1` is still `undefined`. Therefore I had to use the `|| 0` trick.